# Display a p:overlayPanel at a specific position relative to another component (p:graphicImage)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Using a `<p:overlayPanel>` to display a `<p:fileUpload>`, when a `<p:graphicImage>` is clicked as follows.

```
<p:graphicImage id="image"
                library="default"
                name="test/Sunset.jpg"
                style="left: 400px; top: 100px; position: relative;"
                height="200"
                width="200"/>

<p:overlayPanel for="image" my="top left" at="bottom right"
                dynamic="true" showCloseIcon="true" dismissable="true">

    <p:fileUpload mode="advanced"
                  fileLimit="1"
                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
                  fileUploadListener="#{bean.listener}"/>
</p:overlayPanel>
```

When the given `<p:graphicImage>` is clicked, a `<p:fileUpload>` is displayed in a `<p:overlayPanel>` as can be seen in the following picture.

[image]

I however, need to display this `<p:overlayPanel>` (holding a `<p:fileUpload>`) in a way that the **bottom right corner** of this `<p:overlayPanel>` positions over the **top left corner** of the given `<p:graphicImage>` (just because this unnecessarily introduces an ugly horizontal scroll bar on the browser where this is actually implemented (inside a `<p:dataTable>`)).

These attributes `my="top left" at="bottom right"` are expected to do the trick but they do not.

Is this achievable anyway?

---

According to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26584226/1391249), `<p:fileUpload>` looks like the following, when a file is uploaded.

[image]

Which stays away from removing the horizontal scroll bar in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to dynamically resize the `<p:overlayPanel>` with an onshow event to match the `<p:graphicImage>` dimensions.

Here's an example :

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:graphicImage id="img" value="/res/img/img.jpg" />

    <p:overlayPanel id="overlay" for="img" my="right bottom" at="left bottom" onShow="resize();" >
        <p:fileUpload />
    </p:overlayPanel>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function resize() {
            $("[id='form2:overlay']").css("left", "auto");
            $("[id='form2:overlay']").css("right", $("[id='form2:img']").css("width"));
        }
    </script>
</h:form>
```

**EDIT :**

Fixed code to work inside a form.

**EDIT 2:**

Changed code to dynamically position overlay's right side on img's left side.
Since the img in in the last table column on the right, we can just substract img's width from right absolute position.

Comment: Nothing different happens?

Comment: When a file (image) is chosen from the file browser (appended a picture in the question body), `<p:fileUpload>` looks ugly and does not remove the horizontal scroll bar from the browser (as already stated in the question).

Comment: @Tiny My bad I completely misunderstood the question. I provided a code to overlap the `<p:graphicImage>` with the `<p:overlayPanel>`. From your question, you're saying you want `that the bottom right corner of this <p:overlayPanel> positions over the top left corner of the given <p:graphicImage>`. This means you still want to see the image when the panel is open? Also, does the horizontal scrollbar you mention because of the width of the panel or because of its position?

Comment: Whether the image is visible or overlapped by `<p:overlayPanel>` is irrelevant. There is one `<p:dataTable>` expanded horizontally towards the right side to fit the full browser window (horizontally). In the last column of each row of this `<p:dataTable>`, a `<p:graphicImage>` is displayed. A `<p:overlayPanel>` (with `<p:fileUpload>` inside it) is popped up, when this `<p:graphicImage>` is clicked. Because of the display position of this `<p:overlayPanel>`, a horizontal scroll bar is  introduced.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but if `<p:overlayPanel>` is displayed at a specific position as said in the question, then the horizontal scroll bar might disappear but for now, this is uncertain because I'm yet not succeeded in displaying the `<p:overlayPanel>` at that position.

Comment: Thank you but I have not yet succeeded - a tedious activity.

Comment: Visible effects of positioning a `<p:overlayPanel>` can be seen just by using these attributes `at="left top"` and `my="right bottom"` with no JavaScript/jQuery provided that there is enough room on the left side of the given `<p:graphicImage>` to accommodate a `<p:overlayPanel>`. I started a [new thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26633414/1391249) for the rest of the things. Thank you.